# AngularJS: ng-options with filter and ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select with a filter to format the display text and I need to pass the selected value to the controller, but I want to pass the "id" of selected item:

```
<select 
                ng-model="my_field" 
                ng-options="q.name as (q.name | filter1 | filter2) for q in my_fields track by q.id"
                ng-change="controllerMethod(my_field)"
                required>
                </select>

// Controller
    function controllerMethod(selected_field){
       console.log(selected_field);
    }
    $scope.controllerMethod = controllerMethod;


// Filters
    angular.module('app')
        .filter('filter1', function(){ 
            return function(str_value) {
                return str_value ? str_value.split('_').join(' ') : "";
            }
        })

        .filter('filter2', function(){ 
            return function(str_value) {
                return (!!str_value) ? str_value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str_value.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
            }
        })
```

Before I add this filter it was passing all object to the controller. Now, it's passing the "q.name" (the label). How can I pass the id of selected object?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your filter & controller.

Comment: @lin ok I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need you change your `ng-options` to the following:

```
ng-options="q as (q.name | filter1 | filter2) for q in my_fields track by q.id"
```

With the way you have yours set up, the `track by` expression evaluates to `q.name.id` which will be undefined. The code I've added above should evaluate to `q.id` which I believe is what you're after. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w75mm9sc/) to see if that's what you're wanting.